# Merging two columns with non-unique rows and NaNs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two columns in a dataframe df:

```
   A    B
0  NaN  NaN
1  3.14 NaN
2  NaN  4.20
3  3.65 0.68
```

Intended result for df:

```
   A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  3.14 NaN  3.14
2  NaN  4.20 4.20
3  3.65 0.68 3.65
```

What's the pandas equivalent for?

```
if(A == np.nan):
    if(B == np.nan):
        C = np.nan
    else: 
        C == B
else:
    C = A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `bfill`

```
df['C']=df.bfill(1).iloc[:,0]

df
      A     B     C
0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  3.14   NaN  3.14
2   NaN  4.20  4.20
3  3.65  0.68  3.65
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Suppose I had other columns 'D', 'E', and so on in my original df... how would I create 'C' from only columns 'A' and 'B'?

Comment: @plummms df[[‘A’,’B’]].bfill(1).iloc[,0]